# QuaZIP unable to open password protected file error 103

Tags: c++, qt, zip, compression, quazip

I'm trying to open a password protected ZIP file using QuaZIP in Qt but it isn't working. It works nicely if I remove password protection from the zip file. Here's my code

```
QuaZip zip("/media/ferhan/Education_material_and_setups/compressiontest/test.zip");
zip.open(QuaZip::mdUnzip);
QuaZipFile file(&zip);
for(bool f=zip.goToFirstFile(); f; f=zip.goToNextFile()) {
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly, "password");
    if(!file.isOpen())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Error : "<<file.getZipError()<<endl ;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"File is open!"<<endl;
        file.close();
    }
}
zip.close();
```

The error string shows error code 103. I tried to search for this error code but found nothing.

Some info about my ZIP file

> 7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
>   p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)
>   Processing archive: /media/ferhan/Education_material_and_setups/compressiontest/test.zip
>   Testing     drunk.jpg
>   Testing     monday-motivate-11.jpg
>   Testing     very-clever-25.jpg
>   Everything is Ok
>   Files: 3
>   Size:       90350
>   Compressed: 89128

Can anybody help?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137725/quazip-password-protected-files) example.

Comment: Maybe you should go to rhe QuaZip issue tracker?